# Accessing javascript object's properties in the method

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the below code snippet i am expecting the answer as "number" but i am getting it as "undefined". Can anyone please help me here to find out why its returning "undefined" ?

```
var foo = {
    bar: function () {
        return this.baz;
    },
    baz: 1
};

(function () {
    return typeof arguments[0](); //this will return "undefined"
})(foo.bar);
```

If i do typeof foo.bar(), then it will give me the expected answer as "number".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `this` with normal functions is set by *how the function is called*, not where it's defined. (ECMAScript2015's "arrow" functions are different, they inherit `this` from where they're created, not how they're called.)

You have a couple of options:

1) Use `Function#bind` to create a new function that, when called, will call your original function with the correct `this`:

```js
var foo = {
  bar: function() {
    return this.baz;
  },
  baz: 1
};
(function() {
  snippet.log(typeof arguments[0]());
})(foo.bar.bind(foo));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

2) Use your own wrapper function:

```js
var foo = {
  bar: function() {
    return this.baz;
  },
  baz: 1
};
(function() {
  snippet.log(typeof arguments[0]());
})(function() {
  return foo.bar.apply(foo, arguments);
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was about to answer the same `var foo = {
    bar: function () {
        console.log(this);
        return this.baz;
    }.bind(foo),
    baz: 1
};

(function () {
    return typeof arguments[0]();
}(foo.bar));`. Anyway +1 for nice explanation

Comment: Thanks Crowder and Tushar. But second way still returns "undefined" isn't it?

Comment: @Parashuram `return foo.bar.apply(foo, arguments);` use `foo` instead of `this`

Comment: TJ is there a reason you have used `arguments` in `(function() { return foo.bar.apply(foo, arguments); })`

Comment: @Tushar: Just to pass on all the arguments given to it. Thanks for the `this/foo` fix, I'd forgotten we were trying to preserve that! :-)

Comment: @Parashuram: I've made the code blocks live examples.